# Not working 'activate terminal node' and 'add_existing_component' in python(pycaita)

Tags: python, product

Here's some simple code for pycatia [PYCATIA site download],
but it seems to be seen not working in my computer.

it looks like File load is totally sucessful.
but all product/cgr is not activated,
becaused of "Do not activate default shapes on open" option in my catia.

Though 'activate_terminal_node' code is commanded, it doen't work properly.

and please let me know how to use 'add_components_from_files' method

thanks in advance

```
from pycatia import catia
from pycatia.enumeration.enumeration_types import cat_work_mode_type
from pycatia.product_structure_interfaces.product import Product

caa = catia()
documents = caa.documents

documents.open(r'D:\CATIA\test.CATProduct')
document = caa.active_document
product = document.product()

product.apply_work_mode(cat_work_mode_type.index("DESIGN_MODE"))

Product.activate_terminal_node(product.get_products())
```